# Manipulating equations in algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $\displaystyle \frac{3a+2b}{a}=\frac{2a+5b}{c}=\frac{5c-2b}{b}$, find $\dfrac{2a-3b}{a+b}$.

I couln't manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Assuming $a+b+c\ne0,$

$$\frac{3a+2b}{a}=\frac{2a+5b}{c}=\frac{5c-2b}{b}=\dfrac{3a+2b+2a+5b+5c-2b}{a+b+c}=?$$

Express $c,b$ in terms of $a$

Comment: Maybe, it should be recalled the following rule alas no longer taught in schools (for long now, at least in my country): $A/B=C/D \implies A/B=C/D=(aA+bB)/(aC+bD)$ for any $a,b$ (as long as the last denominator is not zero...)

Comment: I got it, thanks.